# how to make infinite background in spriteKit swift 4

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I try to make an endless background through the nodes, but the background has not become infinite and is interrupted, the third background is not yet shown. After the first show, the number of nodes in the scene grows, how can this be fixed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


   var bgNode: SKNode!
   var overlay: SKNode!
   var overlayWidth: CGFloat!
   //var viewSize: CGSize!
   var levelPositionX: CGFloat = 0.0
   //var speed: CGFloat = 5.5


   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    setupNode()
    //viewSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 
                                                     
                                              frame.size.height )
    
  }

  func setupNode() {
    let worldNode = childNode(withName: "World")!
    bgNode = worldNode.childNode(withName: "Background")!
    overlay = bgNode.childNode(withName: "Overlay")!.copy() as! 
  SKNode
    overlayWidth = overlay.calculateAccumulatedFrame().width
  }

   func createBackgroundOverlay() {
    let backgroundOverlay = overlay.copy() as! SKNode
    backgroundOverlay.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    
    bgNode.addChild(backgroundOverlay)
    levelPositionX += overlayWidth
}

func update() {
    bgNode.position.x -= 5
    if bgNode.position.x <= -self.frame.size.width {
         bgNode.position.x = self.frame.size.width * 2
        createBackgroundOverlay()
        
      }
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
      update()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my endless runner game, I have implemented an endless background and a ground(or floor) much similar to your app. Below I shall discuss the steps i have used in my game.

**Step 1:** In your GameScene.swift file add these variables.

```
var backgroundSpeed: CGFloat = 80.0 // speed may vary as you like
var deltaTime: TimeInterval = 0
var lastUpdateTimeInterval: TimeInterval = 0
```

**Step 2:** In GameScene file, make **setUpBackgrouds** method as follows

```
func setUpBackgrounds() {
    //add background

    for i in 0..<3 {
        // add backgrounds, my images were namely, bg-0.png, bg-1.png, bg-2.png

        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg-\(i).png")
        background.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        background.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * size.width, y: 0.0)
        background.size = self.size
        background.zPosition = -5
        background.name = "Background"
        self.addChild(background)

    }

    for i in 0..<3 {
        // I have used one ground image, you can use 3
        let ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Screen.png")
        ground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        ground.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: ground.size.height)
        ground.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * size.width, y: 0)
        ground.zPosition = 1
        ground.name = "ground"
        self.addChild(ground)

    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Now we have to capture timeIntervals from update method

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if lastUpdateTimeInterval == 0 {
        lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime
    }

    deltaTime = currentTime - lastUpdateTimeInterval
    lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime
}
```

**Step 4:** Here comes the most important part, moving our backgrounds and groungFloor by enumerating child nodes. Add these two methods in GameScene.swift file.

```
func updateBackground() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Background") { (node, stop) in

        if let back = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            let move = CGPoint(x: -self.backgroundSpeed * CGFloat(self.deltaTime), y: 0)
            back.position += move

            if back.position.x < -back.size.width {
                back.position += CGPoint(x: back.size.width * CGFloat(3), y: 0)
            }
        }

    }
}

func updateGroundMovement() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "ground") { (node, stop) in

        if let back = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            let move = CGPoint(x: -self.backgroundSpeed * CGFloat(self.deltaTime), y: 0)
            back.position += move

            if back.position.x < -back.size.width {
                back.position += CGPoint(x: back.size.width * CGFloat(3), y: 0)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Step 5:** At this point you should get this error:"Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two 'CGPoint' operands" in updateBackground and updateGroundMovement methods.
[image: Error Messages]

Now we need to implement operator overloading to resolve this problem. Create a new Swift File and name it Extensions.swift and then implement as follows:

```
//  Extensions.swift

import CoreGraphics
import SpriteKit

public func + (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
   return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

public func += (left: inout CGPoint, right: CGPoint) {
   left = left + right
}
```

**Step 6:** call **setUpBackgrounds** method in didMove(toView:)

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    setUpBackgrounds()

}
```

**Step 7:** Finally call the **updateBackground** and **updateGroundMovement** methods in update(_ currentTime) method. updated code is given below:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if lastUpdateTimeInterval == 0 {
        lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime
    }

    deltaTime = currentTime - lastUpdateTimeInterval
    lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime

    //MARK:- Last step:- add these methods here
    updateBackground()
    updateGroundMovement()
}
```